# How to detect what thread and where it crashes?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

Im using XMPP framework for iOS and it crashes sometimes. Whenever Im debugging it never crashes it happens always when Im running the app.

So I would like to know how to detect where is this happening.

This is the error message I get when it happens.

```
[Switching to thread 20483]
[Switching to thread 20483]
(gdb) continue
[Switching to thread 11523]
[Switching to thread 11523]
2011-11-18 16:37:45.301 [559:9e0b] bool _WebTryThreadLock(bool), 0x2e2710: Tried to obtain the web lock from a thread other than the main thread or the web thread. This may be a result of calling to UIKit from a secondary thread. Crashing now...
[Switching to thread 20483]
[Switching to thread 20483]
Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
kill
quit
```

I was getting more of these before but I was able to detect them, but not this one...

Answer (score 0):

You can try organizer in the menu under item window and console shows what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable so called Zombies to help track such errors. With Zombies your objects don't get deallocated completely if you deallocate them, so when you refer to an object that "doesn't exist" it actually still there.
Usually you can see the exact line of your code that caused EXC_BAD_ACCESS.